# javascript -- converting string to array of tuples

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, tuples

I have a string that I want to convert into array

`"[(6, 11), (12, 17), (18, 20)]"`

`.split()` wouldn't work (or at least I don't know how to separate the words) and JSON.parse always craps out with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

I'm converting like this: `JSON.parse(THAT_GIVEN_LIST)`

Am I doing something wrong? How do I make this string into a nice list of `[(6, 11), (12, 17), (18, 20)]`

Comment: A tuple is not a data structure in JavaScript.

Comment: that format is not JSON, hence the SyntaxError. What object structure do you actually intend to create?

Comment: `[(6, 11), (12, 17), (18, 20)]` in js will become `[11, 17, 20]` ;)

Comment: I guess what you want is `[[6, 11], [12, 17], [18, 20]]`

Comment: If it is, and your data is as posted, then `JSON.parse(str.replace(/\(/g, '[').replace(/\)/g, ']'));`

Comment: I can change the tuple to array. would that make transforming easier?

Comment: Yes. In that case `JSON.parse(THAT_GIVEN_LIST)` would suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses that you are using are not syntactically correct for JSON.  You pose that they mean to define a tuple.  However, tuples are not JSON primitives.  If you want to have nested structures like this, your best bet will be to use nested arrays:

```js
const a = "[[6, 11], [12, 17], [18, 20]]";
const aa = JSON.parse(a);
console.log(aa);

aa.forEach(i => console.log(`first: ${i[0]}, second: ${i[1]}`));
```

Comment: I see. So tuple is no good. I'll give it a try using `[]` instead

Answer (score 3):

Having your input format as python list, you can do it in next way:

```
'use strict';

const tuple = "[(6, 11), (12, 17), (18, 20)]";

const tupleToArray = JSON.parse(tuple
  .replace(/\(/g, '[')
  .replace(/\)/g, ']')
);

console.log(tupleToArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `JSON.parse()` to get the 2-D array. Replaced occurences of `"("` with `"["` and `")"` with `"]"`.

```js
var arr = JSON.parse("[(6, 11), (12, 17), (18, 20)]".split("(").join("[").split(")").join("]"));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You don't need `eval` for this.

Comment: @zero298: I guess because of security reasons? I changed it to `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like I did below. Basically I removed all the white-space from the original string then used regex and `split` the string into an array. Finally I used another regex and spread operator to `map` the formatted strings to a new array:

```js
var s = "[(6, 11), (12, 17), (18, 20)]";

function makeTuple(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/\s/g, "")
    .split("),(")
    .map(el => [...el.replace(/[\[()\]]/g, '').split(',')]);
}

console.log(makeTuple(s));
```